# Understanding assignment of pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main( ) 
{ 
    int s[5][2] = { { 1234, 56 }, { 1212, 33 }, { 1434, 80 }, { 1312, 78 } } ;
    int ( *p )[2];
    int i, j, *pint ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i <= 3 ; i++ ) 
    { 
        p = &s[i] ;
        pint = (int *)p ;
        printf ( "\n" ) ; 
        for ( j = 0 ; j <= 1 ; j++ ) 
            printf ( "%d ", *( pint + j ) ) ; 
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
1234 56
1212 33 
1434 80 
1312 78
```

Why is 2 used in `int(*p)[2]`. Can't we use 3,4 or any other number?
What is the meaning of (int *)p?
Also what is the significance of `p=&s[i];` in the code?

Comment: I can't see `int(*p)[2]` anywhere in your code. Could you please edit your question and add some context? Also, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you can read about creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: An array `T[5]` can be accessed via pointer arithmetic on a pointer of type `T*`. That's what you're doing. For you, `T = int[2]`. You cannot access the array via some other, unrelated pointer `U*`.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's pointer to array of two `int`s and is assigned the elements of `s` which are arrays of two `int`s as well (must match the last dimension (s) from that array).

It's actually not necessary here because it's just temporary variable which is immediately assigned to `pint`, so it could assigned directly from `s[i]` to `pint`.

Additionally the expression you asked aboutis wrong:

```
    pint = (int *)p ;
```

It should be:

```
    pint = *p ;
```

Which is semantically correct. The first one only because the pointer points to the same memory where the array begins but it's very error prone as there is no check by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `s` is a 5×2 array. In C a 2-D array is an array of arrays, so `s` is implemented as an array of five arrays of two elements.

A pointer can be used to access array elements if the type of the pointer matches the type of an array element. Therefore, to access a 5×2 array you need a pointer to an array of two. The syntax for declaring such pointer in C is as follows:

```
int(*p)[2]
```

> Cant we use 3,4 or any other number?

No. The number must match the size of the element array of `s` in order for the assignment to work correctly.

> what is the significance of `p=&s[i];` in the code?

The meaning is the same as with any other kind of array: `&s[i]` produces a pointer to element `i` of array `s`. An equivalent expression is `p = s+i;`

Comment: Also What is the meaning of (int *)p?

Comment: @ChiranjevKoul That's a cast expression, converting `p` to a pointer to `int` (i.e. to `int*`).